# Create 1 common page template for different terms of custom taxonomy in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

**My Need** ( More Idea's are welcome )
I need a page for each term, So when i click on a playlist only the songs which belongs to the playlist (term) will be listed.

---

**My Present Situation**
I am using archive-{post-name}.php for my Custom taxonomy which lists all my Songs from different playlists ( Terms ). I am trying to pass Get values in archive-{postname} but Its not working too ( redirects to homepage )

---

**My Research**
My research is leading me to  custom taxonomy templates.------- taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php tag-{slug}.php tag-{id}.php category-{slug}.php category-{ID}.php 
But I can't see **how does my need gets addressed?**, a Common page for each single Term

Answer (score 1):

Template hierarchy of wordpress taxomonies :

- taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php
- taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php
- tag-{slug}.php
- tag-{id}.php
- category-{slug}.php
- category-{ID}.php

from [Docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/).

Answer (score 0):

The category.php, tag.php, and taxonomy.php templates allow posts filtered by taxonomy to be treated differently from unfiltered posts or posts filtered by a different taxonomy. (Note: post refers to any post type – posts, pages, custom post types, etc.). These files let you target specific taxonomies or specific taxonomy terms. For example:

taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php,taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php,tag-{slug}.php,tag-{id}.php,category-{slug}.php,category-{ID}.php
So you could format all posts in an animal taxonomy named news on a page that looks different from posts filtered in other categories.
for more information, [click here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/)

Comment: Thanks Ajeet ! I would like to know, if I click on a Term ( eg: Carnivorous ), I want to pass the value of the term on the page which is being used ( may be Taxonomy-taxonomy.php ) to know I have selected Carnivorous

Comment: For example, if the taxonomy is named “sometax,” and the taxonomy’s term is “someterm,” WordPress would look for a file named taxonomy-sometax-someterm.php

Comment: Oh ! That sounds cool. How about i don't want to create a separate page for  someterm and want all terms ( someterm1 to N ) to be handled by taxonomy-sometax.php . Passing the GET values are not working as well

Answer (score 0):

I would like say to create a new "taxonomy-customtaxonomy.php" and use this code as below.

```
<?php 
$audio_tax = get_queried_object();

$term_audios = 
get_terms( array(
'taxonomy'      => 'customtaxonomy',
'hide_empty'    => false,
'parent'    => $audio_tax->term_id,
) );
?>
```

Do observe the magic.

Comment: I realize I already have a file "taxonomy-playlist", I have been trying to use http://localhost/startup/krishighar/video/playlist/uncategorized/ where Video is "Custom Post Name" and Playlist is "Custom Category" But it redirects to homepage. Is there a problem with URL

Comment: Dear Razen, How can I see your localhost URL.... do upload the project on live server so that I can able to look after your problem.